R cannot find function ggplot_na_distribution
I'm trying to find missing values in a time series by using the function ggplot_na_distribution, but I get this result: could not find function "ggplot_na_distribution".
I have installed, uninstalled, and reinstalled the ggplot2 package including dependencies and I'm loading ggplot2 correctly. I'm running R version 4.3.3 with ggplot2 version 3.5.0.

That function is in the imputeTS package, so you need to load that first.

Thank you. For some reason, everywhere was telling me to load ggplot2 instead.
